# How to show labels in curved pattern in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

When I am trying to show label of these roads parallel almost all roads are showing, but in curved type visibility of labels are getting reduced. How I can show all roads names curved to road?

Using QGIS v2.18.20 in Windows.

[image]

Comment: try change maximum angle between curved characters in "Placement" field or check 'show all labels for this layer' in "Rendering"

Comment: Tried with all options, Still there is no change.

Comment: try: Label polygons using curved labels along the perimeter.

Comment: These are all lines, Can I apply perimeter concept here as well? If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

May be you could try this two options:

1. In case your lines come from several files, you can set priority to highest in all of them (label properties).
   [image]
2. In case, all your labels come from one layer, you can show all labels, even if they overlap because of the size or whatever.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is probably too late to help you but in case it helps others. I was having this same issue and have just resolved it.

It turned out my polylines were multipart features an QGIS was only labeling one part.

In `Label -> Rendering` options check to boxes marked "`Label every part of multipart features`" and "`Merge connected lines to avoid duplicates`"

[image]